# USB and UART simultaneous power to Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, power, usb, communication, uart

I am connecting an Arduino Mega (Crius) to a Intel Embedded processor (Minnowboard) via the following to Peripherals:

1. Minnowboard USB            -> Arduino      (to flash the micro-controller)
2. Minnowbaord Highspeed UART -> Arduino UART (to communicate)

Now both the peripherals are supplying +5V Vcc to the Arduino from the Minnowbaord but via different ports. Both the channels shall always remain connected.

Is it safe to power +5V from different ports to the Arduino (because i am technically bypassing all the voltage regulators available on board) ?

Will this cause any problems for the Arduino in regards to difference in voltage levels?

Comment: A UART connection does not normally provide power.  Some particular cables like those often found on FTDI USB converters might, but that's not actually part of the UART connection, but rather something passed through from the USB.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly fine.  As it's the same 5V source the voltage *should* be the same and it'll just combine them together as if you had 2 wires in parallel.  However, if there are things like diodes in the path of one connection that causes the voltage to be slightly lower then the increased voltage imposed on the lower voltage side would reverse bias those diodes and end up cutting off that one source, so only one would be used.

So no, it's nothing to concern yourself over.